# Is there any way to know when resources in user_beancounters hit barrier

Tags: vps, openvz

When I look at `/proc/user_beancounters` there is some failcnt on `kmemsize` and `tcpsndbbuf`. Is there anyway to know when they got incremented? Do we always need to track the count and display in graph or something?

Answer (score 0):

there are a few solutions for zabbix, monit, nagios;

http://binfalse.de/software/nagios/check_ubc-pl/ 

 https://github.com/peletiah/openvz 

 http://wiki.openvz.org/Monitoring_/proc/user_beancounters_via_vzwatchd 

 http://www.admon.org/shell-script-to-monitor-openvz-container-running-status/

i believe you will find something for you :)

Comment: thanks for the tips. so I guess there is no way to know when it hit limit in the past unless I had been monitoring it?